# How to solve it without using 'arguments' but with ...rest?

Tags: javascript, typescript

**My teacher said that i can solve it without using arguments in const args, but with using ...rest**
**im not really good with this operator so i need help with that. Use rest and give types to all arguments**

```
function destroyer(arr: number[]) {
  const args = arr.slice.call(arguments,1);

  function remove(toDel: number) {
    return args.indexOf(toDel) === -1;
  }
  return arr.filter(remove);
}

const result = destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 1, 3);
console.log(result);
```

**(In this function second and others arguments removes themselves from first arguments, and ([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 1, 3) output [2, 2] after deleting all 1 and 3.)**

Comment: Please may you add the output you want?

Comment: destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 1, 3) will remove 1 and 3 from array and output [2,2]

Comment: It seems like you want something like `destroyer(a, ...b) => a.filter(x => !b.includes(x));`?

Comment: maybe he means const result = destroyer([...[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 1, 3]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You can use [Rest syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
function destroyer(arr, ...args) {
  function remove(toDel) {
    return args.indexOf(toDel) === -1
  }
  return arr.filter(remove)
}

const result = destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 1, 3)

console.log(result)
```

### Using simpler approach

```js
function destroyer(a, ...b) {
  return a.filter(x => !b.includes(x))
}

const result = destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 1, 3)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: yeah, thanks, seems thats right!